# How to embed a PDF in a Mobile Web App

Tags: html, mobile, embed

I am trying to embed a pdf in my mobile web app and I can't seem to get the pdf to automatically scale to the width of the device.

I have the following code to show the pdf.

```
    <embed type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" src="file.pdf" />
```

If I remove the viewport specification the pdf scales correctly so I am wondering if there is a value I should be changing in this that would allow it to show correctly?

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Any help would be great, 
thanks

Answer (score -3):

You really shouldn't be embedding PDF's for a mobile app. Let the phone's native capabilities handle displaying a PDF. `<a target="_blank" href="file.pdf">PDF</a>`